# Creating a script in AHK that will move the window over, put it in fullscreen, and move it back over

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to create a script that will (in google chrome) go to the second monitor and throw the window in fullscreen. and when you press the given button again, it will take it out of fullscreen and move it back over to the first monitor.

here is what i have so far

```
#b::
Send, {LWin Down}{LShift Down}{RIGHT}{LShift Up}{LWin Up}{f11}
```

This works to an extend, it moves the window to the other monitor but if i want to move it back over i have to take it out of fullscreen, move it over into fullscreen, then take it out of fullscreen. This isn't very user friendly. If anyone could help me out with this I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

**Version 1**
If you put Chrome manually to fullscreen, then you can move Chrome to other screen with this code:

```
#b::
    Send, {f11}{LWin Down}{LShift Down}{RIGHT}{LShift Up}{LWin Up}{f11} 
return
```

**Version 2**
It will make fulscreen and move to other screen and then if you press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> again it will move to other screen. But if between these movements you press <kbd>F11</kbd> then it will not work.

```
#b::
    if (f="" || f=0)
    {
        Send, {LWin Down}{LShift Down}{RIGHT}{LShift Up}{LWin Up}{f11} 
        f=1
    }
    else
    {
        Send, {f11}{LWin Down}{LShift Down}{RIGHT}{LShift Up}{LWin Up}{f11} 
    }
return
```

*Also, always use AutoHotkey and its documenatation from http://ahkscript.org/ (current uptodate version, new official website)! AutoHotkey and its documentation from autohotkey.com is outdated and you may have some problems using them!*

Comment: Thanks vasili111, unfortunately this won't work for me. I need the end user to be able to type win+B and have it go to the second monitor and throw it in fullscreen. Do you have any other suggestiosn?

Comment: @BlakeWilson Check **Version 2**. I did not know how to detect that Chrome is in fullscreen mode. If we can determine in which mode is Chrome now, then we can do exactly what you need.

Comment: We're definitely getting there! Is there a way instead of typing alt+shift+right that we could give each monitor a unique name, or even like monitor 1 and monitor 2? that way we can give certain commands to a certain monitor?

Comment: @BlakeWilson You can get monitor name with SysGet ( http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/SysGet.htm ). What alt+shift+right mean?

Comment: I'm sorry, i meant alt+win+right. It basically switches a window to a different monitor. WIth SysGet how could you know which monitor is which?

Comment: @BlakeWilson. Sorry. To get current coordinates of Chrome you need `WinGetPos` command. Look here for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/956224/get-available-screen-area-in-autohotkey

Comment: @BlakeWilson Try to get coordinates of Chrome with `WinGetPos` command and use them in `ImageSearch` command to find if Chrome is fullscreen or not. Then based on that send necessary keys.

Comment: Hey @vasili111 check out my post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26078728/make-second-monitor-go-fullscreen-with-ahk I've added a lot more and i just need one little step to finish it.