# Make second monitor go fullscreen with AHK

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, keyboard-events

I have this Autohotkeys script and I need help on it. By pressing win+b the window will move the the other monitor, in this case monitor 2. I would like for whenever it goes to monitor 2 to also throw it in fullscreen using the keyboard shortcut f11, then when sent back over to monitor 1 take it out of fullscreen, then throw it over. Is this possible? This is what I have now.

```
SysGet, Mon1, Monitor, 1
SysGet, Mon2, Monitor, 2

#b::
winget,windowtomove,id,A    ;move active window
gosub windowmove
return

windowmove:
if not mon2left
return
wingetpos,x1,y1,w1,h1,ahk_id %windowtomove%
winget,winstate,minmax,ahk_id %windowtomove%
m1:=(x1+w1/2>mon1left) and (x1+w1/2<mon1right) and (y1+h1/2>mon1top) and (y1+h1/2<mon1bottom) ? 1:2   ;works out if centre of window is on monitor 1 (m1=1) or monitor 2 (m1=2)
m2:=m1=1 ? 2:1  ;m2 is the monitor the window will be moved to
ratiox:=abs(mon%m1%right-mon%m1%left)-w1<5 ? 0:abs((x1-mon%m1%left)/(abs(mon%m1%right-mon%m1%left)-w1))  ;where the window fits on x axis
ratioy:=abs(mon%m1%bottom-mon%m1%top)-h1<5 ? 0:abs((y1-mon%m1%top)/(abs(mon%m1%bottom-mon%m1%top)-h1))   ;where the window fits on y axis
x2:=mon%m2%left+ratiox*(abs(mon%m2%right-mon%m2%left)-w1)   ;where the window will fit on x axis in normal situation
y2:=mon%m2%top+ratioy*(abs(mon%m2%bottom-mon%m2%top)-h1)
w2:=w1   
h2:=h1   ;width and height will stay the same when moving unless reason not to lower in script

if abs(mon%m1%right-mon%m1%left)-w1<5 or abs(mon%m2%right-mon%m2%left-w1)<5   ;if x axis takes up whole axis OR won't fit on new screen
   {
   x2:=mon%m2%left   
   w2:=abs(mon%m2%right-mon%m2%left)
   }
if abs(mon%m1%bottom-mon%m1%top)-h1<5 or abs(mon%m2%bottom-mon%m2%top)-h1<5
   {
   y2:=mon%m2%top
   h2:=abs(mon%m2%bottom-mon%m2%top)
   }
if winstate   ;move maximized window
   {
   winrestore,ahk_id %windowtomove%
   winmove,ahk_id %windowtomove%,,mon%m2%left,mon%m2%top
   winmaximize,ahk_id %windowtomove%
   }
else
   {
   if (x1<mon%m1%left)
      x2:=mon%m2%left   ;adjustments for windows that are not fully on the initial monitor (m1)
   if (x1+w1>mon%m1%right)
      x2:=mon%m2%right-w2
   if (y1<mon%m1%top)
      y2:=mon%m2%top
   if (y1+h1>mon%m1%bottom)
      y2:=mon%m2%bottom-h2
   winmove,ahk_id %windowtomove%,,x2,y2,w2,h2   ;move non-maximized window
   }
return
```

Thanks for any of your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed possible, here you go:

```
sysGet, d2, monitor, 2
#ifWinActive ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
#b::
    winGetPos, cx, cy, a
    winGet, style, style
    if !(style & 0xC00000)
        send {f11}
    send {blind}+#{right}
    if !(((cx >= d2Left && cx <= d2Right) or (cx >= d2Right && cx <= d2Left)) and ((cy >= d2Top && cy <= d2Bottom) or (cy >= d2Bottom && cy <= d2Top)))
        send {f11}
return
```